# Bash - Execute cleanup code when script is terminated using Terminal GUI "Close"

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I'm not even sure there is a way to do this, as I've been searching all day and it would seem to be I would have to `trap SIGKILL` (which I know cannot be caught by `trap`) but ...

Using SIGTERM and SIGINT, I have my current script perform cleanup operations to revert temporary changes to the hard disk etc when Ctrl+C is hit. That works perfectly. If I close the Terminal window however (by clicking the red traffic light), I get asked if I would like to terminate the currently running processes, but clicking "Close" doesn't seem to actually terminate the script. I can tell this because log files keep getting updated with info and other parts of the script still run.

So my question is, what signal is sent to the script when you close the GUI window, if any? If none, or uncatchable, how can I avoid the script running if the GUI is closed or terminate the previous script's occurrence the next time it's run?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to trap script termination is to simply use the reserved word `EXIT` there. As in:

```
trap "echo bye" EXIT
```

(I don't have OSX to test out specific case, though)